# C++ Iterator vs object with a length() method

Tags: c++, iterator, idioms

My question references an example from the [Maya C++ API](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/mayasdk2012/en_us/index.html) and I am wondering if it is specific to Maya or a general C++ idiom

In the Maya API, there is an object called `MSelectionList`, which is a container that represents objects in the scene. It also has a companion `MItSelectionList` which is an iterator for a `MSelectionList` instance.

Now I understand that the benefit of an iterator is for it to know how to loop over an object properly, but in this case the `MSelectionList` has a `.length()` method, as well as the same getters as the iterator, except you provide the index.

Example...

**[MSelectionList](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/mayasdk2012/en_us/cpp_ref/class_m_selection_list.html)**

```c++
MSelectionList activeList;
MGlobal::activeSelectionList(activeList);

unsigned int length = activeList.length();
for (unsigned int i=0 ; i < length; i++ ) {
    MDagPath item;
    iter.getDagPath(i, item);
}
```

**[MItSelectionList](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/mayasdk2012/en_us/cpp_ref/class_m_it_selection_list.html)**

```c++
MSelectionList activeList;
MGlobal::activeSelectionList(activeList);
MItSelectionList iter( activeList );

for ( ; !iter.isDone(); iter.next() ) {
    MDagPath item;
    iter.getDagPath(item);
}
```

The only thing that the iterator provides over the normal selection object is the ability to set a filter type, so that it will only return objects matching a filter. Though you could perform this same test explicitly in the first example.

My question is what would be the benefit of the iterator when there is overlap like this in functionality between the iterator and the original object? Is this just a Maya-specific design decision, or is it a general C++ idiom to always create iterators for some extra reason that I am not understanding here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Maya, but I believe this question is related to the argument between "iterators vs indexing".

According to the [wikipedia article for iterators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#Contrasting_with_indexing), iterators have the following advantages:

> - Counting loops are not suitable to all data structures, in particular
>     to data structures with no or slow random access, like lists or trees.
> - Iterators can provide a consistent way to iterate on data structures
>     of all kinds, and therefore make the code more readable, reusable, and
>     less sensitive to a change in the data structure.
> - An iterator can
>     enforce additional restrictions on access, such as ensuring that
>     elements can not be skipped or that a previously visited element can
>     not be accessed a second time.
> - An iterator may allow the container
>     object to be modified without invalidating the iterator. For instance,
>     once an iterator has advanced beyond the first element it may be
>     possible to insert additional elements into the beginning of the
>     container with predictable results. With indexing this is problematic
>     since the index numbers must change.

For your particular example, it looks like the third bullet is most applicable because `MItSelectionList` only exposes a `next()` member function to enforce that elements are not skipped over (unless a filter is applied).

Comment: Thanks for the info. So would you wager that it's mostly a convenience in the case of this specific set of classes? Because like I was suggesting, I could apply that same filter operation manually by checking the types, but its obviously more code for me. I'm not entirely clear on the benefit of the `next` protecting a detrimental skipping of elements.

Comment: @jdi: Perhaps convenience and readability is part of it, but I would say that it also enforces a stricter set of rules and prevents more mistakes (although for a trivial example, this might not be apparent).